# string to float

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to convert a string into a float.
I have a string that consists out of a number and some letters, I am using regex to remove the letters.

This is what I currenlty have:

```
            string x = "0.5AA";


            Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(Regex.Match(x.ToString(), @"(\d)+\.(\d+)").Value.Replace('.', ',')));
```

The output is: 0.5

This works if the string looks like 0.5AA, if the string is 100AA it crashes, is there a way to convert the 100AA to 100.0AA?

Comment: Maybe just match "not letter"?

Comment: @Fildor I'm sorry, I'm not following you, the string can consist out of any number combination or letter combination, so I do not know the combination beforehand, so I have nothing to compare, I don't know if that is what you mean?

Comment: `-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` for optinal fractional part

Comment: @PietHendri You don't need to compare. Just throw away what you do _not_ want. That is "everything that is not 0-9 or ." goes out the window, then parse. If you can have more than one number in that string, then it's a different story.

Comment: OT if x is already a string, then you don't need to call .ToString() on it

Comment: Also you should use `float.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of `float.Parse(myString.Replace('.', ','))` otherwise you’re code will break on system where the decimal separator is not a `,`. In general always specify the culture if converting from string to numbers or datetimes.

Comment: @Fildor that won't work for numbers like 0.5e2 or 0.5e-2

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you also need to account for scientific notation like I commented above

Comment: @phuclv Scientific notation was not part of the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
     @"(\d)+(\.(\d)+)?"
```

It will optionally include the floating if they are there

### Update 1

If you want to add the +- optionally change it to the following

```
[+-]?(\d)+(\.(\d)+)?
```

Comment: `@"-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?";` please, note `?` instead of `*`. Otherwise you'll fail on `1.2.3.4`

Comment: This works, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes Dmitry you are right,  I just changed it

Comment: this also fails on -1, 1.2e3 or +1.2e-4

Comment: You are right about positive or negative indicators, but the e notation is not a float expression but a scientific expression used in calculators. The OP did not ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex as below for select only numbers and not analphabets and then parse as float.

```
string x = "100AA";
string numString = Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9.]", "");
Console.WriteLine(numString);
float y = float.Parse(numString);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: this fails miserably on numbers like -100, 1.2e3, 1.3e-4...